# Is entity object managed by spring container?

Tags: spring, spring-roo

As I understand, entity objects in spring web application is commonly generated from DAO, and thus is not managed by spring container. But in spring-roo application, entity, DAO and service live in the same place. I wonder how these objects are managed by Spring container? Does entity object generated from DAO still lives outside of the spring container?

Answer (score 1):

Spring roo by default uses the ActiveRecord pattern which means Dao methods are on the Entity object.  This doesn't mean that the actual objects loaded from the methods are managed by the spring container as such.  Its just a pattern, and you can switch to repository/dao pattern if you prefer.

Also, I am not sure what you mean by managed by the container.
In any spring app, objects loaded from a Dao can have dependancies injected and property values set.  Spring does this using AOP.

Its just a matter of adding the @Configurable annotation to the object being created.